# Scala method type parameter can not accept existential type in forSome form

Tags: scala, types, existential-type

In Scala, an existential type has the following two forms:

```
 // placeholder syntax
 List[_]
 // forSome
 List[T forSome {type T}]
```

However, seems that the second form can not appear in the method type parameter position(at least in the way like I write below).

```
  // placeholder syntax is Okay
  scala> def foo[List[_]](x: List[_]) = x
  foo: [List[_]](x: List[_])List[_]

  scala> def foo[List[t forSome {type t}]](x: List[_]) = x
  <console>:1: error: ']' expected but 'forSome' found.
  def foo[List[T forSome {type T}]](x: List[_]) = x
                  ^

  // being as upper bound is also Okay
  scala> def foo[A <: List[T forSome { type T }]](x: A) = x
  foo: [A <: List[T forSome { type T }]](x: A)A

  // type alias is a possible way but that is not what I want
  scala> type BB = List[T forSome {type T}]
  defined type alias BB

  scala> def foo[BB](x: List[_]) = x
  foo: [BB](x: List[_])List[Any]
```

I have tried for a while but been unable to find the right way to get the second compiled successfully.
So is it just some restrictions about method type parameter, or am i missing something here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The confusion is that the underscore (`_`) in `foo` does **not** denote an existential type.

Let's see what the following actually means:

```
def foo[List[_]](x: List[_]) = x
```

`List` here is a higher kinded type parameter (and by the way does **not** refer to scala's built-in `List` type -- aka `scala.collection.immutable`). This type parameter itself has a single type parameter, denoted by the underscore (`_`).

Now that it's clear that `List[_]` is not an existential here, it follows that `forSome` has no business going there.

However, you can use `forSome` in the type of `x`. The following is equivalent to your original definition of `foo`:

```
def foo[List[_]](x: List[T] forSome { type T }) = x
```

Then again, this is probably still not what you'd want, seeing as `List` is still a type parameter and **not** `scala.collection.immutable`. What you'd probably want is:

```
def foo(x: List[T] forSome { type T }) = x
```

which is the same as:

```
def foo(x: List[_]) = x
```

Answer (score 0):

Hinted by Régis Jean-Gilles's "List here is a higher-kinded type parameter (and by the way does not refer to Scala's built-in List type -- aka scala.collection.immutable)", I had a re-check on the definition of existential type and finally figured out the problem in my case, just write it here as complement for Régis Jean-Gilles's answer.

> Existential types are a means of constructing types where portions of the type signature are existential, where existential means that although **`some real type`** meets that portion of a type signature, we don’t care about the specific type. Existential types were introduced into Scala as a means to interoperate with **`Java’s generic types`**, such as **`Iterator<?> or Iterator<? extends Component>`**(Quote from **`<<Scala In Depth>>`**).

Real type could be type from the library(like the scala.collection.immutable.List), or the self-defined type like type alias BB in my case. Anyway, Scala compiler has to guarantee that **part of the existential type is also known**.

The problem in my case is that

```
 // List is type parameter which accepts another type as parameter
 def foo[List[_]](x: List[_]) = x
 // List may be misleading here, just change it to another name
 def foo[TT[_]](x: TT[_]) = x
```

Scala compiler only knows that TT is higher-kinded type parameter, apparently **no real type exists here**. So in this case, TT[_] is not a existential type therefore forSome form can not be used in the type parameter position.
And the following cases are valid.

```
// we define a higher-kined type HKT, so HKT is a real type 
// when Scala compiler checks the method parameter part
// HKT can be defined as existential type
def foo[HKT[_]](x: HKT[T forSome { type T }]) = x
def foo[HKT[_]](x: HKT[T] forSome { type T }) = x
```